# How 32 bit C# application can utilize a 64 bit DLL

Tags: c#, 32bit-64bit

I've got a C# Application that is 32-bit with a target x86 Installer.  This application can be installed an run on x64 machine no problem.  However, a third party piece of hardware from a vendor (which is integrated into the software) now requires the use of a 64bit DLL whenever we install on x64 systems.

Currently I have placed both the 32bit DLL and 64bit DLL in my project.  However the target x86 Installer obviously doesn't like the 64bit DLL.

Is it possible for me to create a solution whereby I can deploy the 64bit DLL and/or 32bit DLL and still only have one installer project?  (I've looked at third party software called Advanced Installer but I do not know for sure if this will help me achieve the solution I need)

Or is it possible to create a generic Installer project?

Note: Two installer (x86 vs x64) deployments aren't feasible because we have a process for automatic updates I do not want to redefine. Maintaining one MSI file is important to me.

Advice is much appreciated.

Comment: You can do this in NSIS.

Comment: The real problem here is that you won't be able to use the x64 DLL from your x86 application.

Comment: You can't use a 64-bit DLL from a 32-bit process (or vice versa). This is in part because there's no way to translate between the address spaces. See [this post on Raymond Chen's blog for details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/10/20/9006720.aspx). If you want to mix 64-bit and 32-bit, you have to have two processes, and some kind of inter-process communication.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I can compile the project with the 64bit dll without issues. If it wouldn't work with the x86 application, don't you think I'd get errors?

Comment: @Encryption: Have you tested it even once? Compilation is not really an indicator here, especially if the DLL in question is unmanaged.

Comment: Just imported and compiled it this morning, which is when I came across the installer issue

Comment: I can compile a lot of things that don't work worth a darn.

Comment: Is your question about a single installer, or using a 64-bit dll from a 32-bit process?  Or is the 32-bit process the installer?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the file from a x86 MSI is not a problem with Advanced Installer, the following article explains how to do it:
http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-OS-dependent-install.html

Also, if you have two versions of the DLL with the same name that need to be placed in the folder you should look here: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-install-file-with-same-name.html

However, you should first check if your application can correctly load the x64 DLL, as the guys mentioned in their comments.

Comment: Why should he check?  The process is targeted to x86 which means its a 32-bit only process.  Even if it was set to `ANY CPU` if it references a single 32-bit library it would be a 32-bit process.  This also means it would be unable to load any 64-bit library.

Comment: I have taken into account that this DLL might be loaded by the third party component mentioned by Encryption, not directly by his x86 application.